# How to finetune the position of a list bullet/number

Tags: css, css-paged-media, antenna-house

I've made a list in HTML:

```
<ol class="listnumber">
    <li class="listnumber">
        <p class="listnumber">list number</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

When I render this in Antennahouse Formatter, this is the result:
[image]

I can change the indentation of the text in CSS:

```
ol li {
    padding-left: 6.3mm;
    text-indent: 0mm;
    margin-left: 0mm;
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

padding-left is the distance indicated by the dark blue line. 
But I'd like to change the position of the number: it's centered in that 6.3 mm wide space now, and I want to align it to the left side of that space (move the number to the spot indicated by the red line).

The text-indent and margin-left do not influence this position. The only property I can find that influences the position of the number is `list-style-position`, but that only has values `inside` and `outside`.

Is there a way to change the position of this number?

I've tried various permutations of this:

```
li.listnumber:before {
    text-align: left;
}
```

but that has no effect on the autogenerated number.

Comment: You can get even more control if you use a pseudo element with [CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) and hide the browser list style. [Exaggerated example](https://jsfiddle.net/73zpdqx5/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried one solution for this

We have below ***default css property for ol element***

```
  padding-inline-start: 40px;
```

We can override this property as below

```
 padding-inline-start: 10px;
```

Below is the code snippet

```css
ol {
  padding-inline-start: 10px;
}

li {
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-indent: 0mm;
    margin-left: 0mm;
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

```html
<ol class="listnumber">
    <li class="listnumber">
        <p class="listnumber">list number</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I hope it will help
Thanks...

Comment: AH Formatter does not currently implement `padding-inline-start`.

Comment: @TonyGraham We can do it by adding `padding-left: 10px` to ol element as well

Comment: @ShirrangKadale: True, but `padding-inline-start` is being ignored as an unknown property, so specifying any value of `padding-inline-start` won't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

`ol` has default `padding-left: 40px;` see [Default CSS Values for HTML Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)

you can easily change the `ol` `padding-left` with:

```
ol.listnumber{
   padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```css
ol.listnumber {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
ol li {
    padding-left: 6.3mm;
    text-indent: 0mm;
    margin-left: 0mm;
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

```html
<ol class="listnumber">
    <li class="listnumber">
        <p class="listnumber">list number</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Interesting. This works in my browser, but not in Antennahouse Formatter.

Comment: In AHF, the property I need to change is padding-inline-start (as in one of the other answers).

Comment: The default styles for AH Formatter are in `html.css` in or under the AH Formatter installation directory.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf66/ahf-env.html#html.css and https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf66/ahf-tech.html#default-css.  In it, the default padding for lists is specified in `em`, not `px`.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the  list-style-position to inside, you can define the red line by the padding-left of the ol. See Example and hover over the list to see the effect, I added a border for visualisation purposes.

```css
ol {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 0; /* or whatever*/
}

ol:hover {
  padding-left: 6mm;
}

ol li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol li p {
  padding-left: 6.3mm;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol class="listnumber">
  <li class="listnumber">
    <p class="listnumber">list number</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link, it explains how you can remove the predefined bullet styles and create your own bullet with desired style:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_bullet_color.asp

```
ul {
    list-style: none; /* Remove default bullets */
}

ul li::before {
  content: "\2022";  /* Add content: \2022 is the CSS Code/unicode for a bullet */
  color: red; /* Change the color */
  font-weight: bold; /* If you want it to be bold */
  display: inline-block; /* Needed to add space between the bullet and the text */
  width: 1em; /* Also needed for space (tweak if needed) */
  margin-left: -1em; /* Also needed for space (tweak if needed) */
}
```

Hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: I've done this in the past, and it works, but has potential complications for numbered lists.

Answer (score 1):

Give the `::marker` a width and left-align its content:

```
li::marker {
  text-align: start;
  width: 6.3mm;
}
```